# How to make groupby get rid of the column you're groupbying

Tags: python, pandas

Is there an innate way to drop the column you're grouping by when using the `groupby` operation?

By that, I mean, suppose you have a dataframe `df` with columns `dt` and `values`, and you run `groups = df.groupby("dt")`.

When iterating over `groups`

```
for start_dt, sub_df in groups:
```

you will see that sub_df still contains `dt`. Is there a natural way to drop this column with `groupby`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is expected that the column is preserved, `groupby` just splits the DataFrame in groups (the behavior might be different if you use `apply` or `agg`). You thus have to drop the column manually.

If you don't mind mutating the input you can use

```
for k, g in df.groupby(df.pop('dt')):
    print(g)
```

Else:

```
for k, g in df.drop(columns='dt').groupby(df['dt']):
    print(g)
```

Example output:

```
   col1  col2
0     0     0
1     1     1
   col1  col2
2     2     2
3     3     3
   col1  col2
4     4     4
5     5     5
```

Used input:

```
  dt  col1  col2
0  A     0     0
1  A     1     1
2  B     2     2
3  B     3     3
4  C     4     4
5  C     5     5
```

Comment: In the first example, does `df.groupby(df.pop('dt'))` still groupby `dt`?

Comment: Yes, as shown in my example ;)

Comment: ohh I misunderstood what `pop` does. I thought it returns `df` without `dt` column, but it actually returns `dt` column. makes sense now

Comment: But be aware that `pop` mutates the original `df`, if you `print(df)` afterwards, the column is gone! To avoid that if this is an issue use the second code